# Android Seek Bar in Status Bar

Tags: android, notificationmanager

I'm developing an android application where i want to add the volume control in Status Bar. Can i add a seek bar inside the Status Bar.

I have worked with `NotificationManager` and i've found that adding animation is difficult in Notification bar.

But can anyone please suggest if i can add a seek bar in my Status Bar(Notification bar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You can't add listeners to the widgets placed on the `NotificationBar`. You can't try adding an `Intent` to call an `Activity` with dialog theme and have the seek bar there.